No terminal bell in Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon
I am missing terminal bell in Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon. The option in terminal preferences is enabled, but still there is no sound. Volume is up, other sounds are played, also I can hear music.
I can make beep through PC Speaker (delete in blacklist and do modprobe) but this is not what I am looking for.
Also sound options lack audio file selection for bell.
Tried pulseaudio advices to change default.pa file, but 1. file does not exist 2. it is not working.
How to make terminal bell work?

Why minus.....?

smurphos on Linux Mint forums has answered:
Menu > Accessibility > Keyboard > Enable Audio Alerts

